# Reply-to autocomplete is blocking Enter from submitting the comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, autocomplete, keyboard

We can submit comments by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Great, I'm always using it and guess many others as well, rarely clicking the button.

When we type `@` followed by a letter (or when there's a commentator with display name starting with unicode character) the autocomplete  box pops up, suggesting possible users to choose from. Excellent and very useful, we can even stick with the keyboard and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to select. Pressing any other key then close the list and all is good in the world, especially when the `@` reply is in the beginning of the comment.

**But**, if we want to have the `@` reply at the end of the comment, or coming back to change the name then want to submit the comment... we press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and nothing happens. Pressing again, still nothing. Third time, using more force... still no icecream and no comment. The focus is on the autocomplete list!

The only way to have our beloved <kbd>Enter</kbd> work again is close the autocomplete list and this can be done only by pressing other key then backspacing it. Not even <kbd>tab</kbd> will close it, just select a name, and <kbd>Esc</kbd>  won't do any good either.

What I suggest is that <kbd>Enter</kbd> will close the autocomplete list, if open, with or without selecting it doesn't really matter.

Comment: This has bothered me, too. But my solution would be different. The Enter key shouldn't do anything related to autocompletion at all. The Tab key should be hooked up to the autocompletion, and the Enter key should *always* submit the comment.

Comment: @Cody so you suggest that TAB will close the autocomplete list in addition to selecting the name? Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Hah! Yes. I never even noticed it doesn't. Truth is, I don't use the autocompletion much. I type fast enough that it really just gets in my way.

Comment: @CodyGray When there is more than one possible completion, Tab circles between the completions. So at least in that case it cannot close the autocompletion UI.

Comment: Perhaps you needed to press it a *fourth* time, with *yet even more force*? Incidentally, I know a guy who is great at replacing ENTER keys on keyboards...

Comment: @AndrewBarber my ENTER has given up long ago, it's a miracle it's still working!

Comment: @Tim nice find!

Comment: Strange, I tried what Gilles suggested and it doesn't work for me. The Tab key *always* auto-fills, it does not do any toggling, even when there are multiple possible matches displayed.

Comment: @Cody for me it auto fills the first then move to the next item, so pressing TAB again will auto fill that item. ENTER cause only the selected item to stay.