# Can't press enter to send comment when user's name is being auto completed

Tags: bug, comments, autocomplete

My cursor is currently at the end of Nicael's name, and the comment is long enough to send:

> [image: Fully auto completed name]

However, if I press enter with my cursor there, I can't send the comment - despite it being a valid comment. If I move the cursor to the non-user-ping text, I can press enter and send it.

The same thing happens if the cursor is the the middle of the full name, or I am typing the name and it is partially complete - enough to show the auto complete:

> [image: non fully auto completed]

This doesn't happen if the user I'm pinging has *edited* the post, and the auto complete doesn't show up:

> [image: no auto complete]
>
> [image: added comment]

Comment: (don't feel bad, [I missed this one too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192449/reply-to-autocomplete-is-blocking-enter-from-submitting-the-comment) ;))